# How can I browse with localstorage disabled?

Tags: html, cross-browser, local-storage

A site I'm building uses localstorage with a fallback to php sessions.

How can I test my website in a localstorage free environment **without downgrading Firefox, Internet Explorer 8, Chrome or Safari?** So I'm probably looking for an add-on for one of these browsers?

I've tried ie7 mode in ie8 - no joy :(

Answer (score 36, accepted):

For Firefox:

> #### [`Dom.storage.enabled`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Dom.storage.enabled)
>
> The Web Applications 1.0 specification defines a mechanism allowing web pages to store information with a web browser (similar to cookies) called “client-side session and persistent storage.” Although use of session storage is subject to a user’s cookie preferences, this preference allows it to be disabled entirely.

For Chrome:

> #### [Chrome/Chromium - disable HTML5 LocalStorage and Databases for all webpages /or ask user](https://superuser.com/questions/298922/chrome-chromium-disable-html5-localstorage-and-databases-for-all-webpages-or-a)
>
> While some resources on the Internet claims that Chrome's cookie blocking does not also block LocalStorage, I just ran a quick test and discovered that it does actually block LocalStorage, (at least in Chrome 12, the current beta version).

For IE:

> #### [Internet Explorer](https://webdevwonders.com/clear-dom-storage/)
>
> Select “Tools” -> “Internet Options” -> “General” -> check “Delete browsing history on exit”, click on “Delete”, check “Cookies”, click on “Delete” once more and restart your browser afterwards.

Not really sure about Safari but I imagine it is similar to Chrome.

Comment: Safari? Anyone?

Comment: For Safari, localstorage stops working when cookies are disabled. Go to settings -> privacy

Answer (score 26):

Start Chrome with option/command-line switch:

```
--disable-local-storage
```

Comment: How do I know its actually disabled once inside Chrome?

Comment: `window.localStorage` gives an error when you try to access it (i.e. via the console).

Answer (score 14):

In Firefox set [`dom.storage.enabled`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Dom.storage.enabled) to `false` in about:config.

Answer (score 4):

Most simple way i've found for Chrome is to disable both Cookies and Local storage. Here's how:

Settings -> "Show advanced settings..." -> "Content settings..." -> "Block sites from setting any data"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable localstorage in IE. Use this

> Select “Internet Options” -> “Advanced” Tab -> Go to
>   “Security” -> uncheck “Enable DOM-Storage”