# How to disable local storage feature in Selenium?

Tags: selenium, local-storage

I want to test the code that must run when the browser does not have / does not allow me to use the local storage feature. Is there any way to mock this behavior on Selenium side?

Comment: which language you are using,with selenium ?

Comment: @Priti I use Python bindings, but I could change, if that was required.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Take a look at this question and the answers:

[How can I browse with localstorage disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600754/how-can-i-browse-with-localstorage-disabled)

It's not specifically about selenium, but it tells you how to configure the browsers to disable local storage; using that, you should be able to run selenium with a browser using that configuration.