# Programmatically disallow sites from using local storage in a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

My chrome extension is currently blocking certain sites from setting `cookies` via their response to an `ajax` request (I strip these out in `chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived`). But I notice that some of these sites also use `window.localStorage` to store similar data. How to block these data from being set (from within the chrome extension)?

Comment: Dont know about extensions, but there is an discussion about it in this link, I think it may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600754/how-can-i-browse-with-localstorage-disabled

Answer (score 0):

> How to block these data from being set (from within the chrome extension)?

Blocking local storage items from being set would require you to modify user browser settings regarding local storage. Seems like contentSettings API does not allow you to do this at this point, check [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSettings), there's no option for enabling/disabling local storage.

What you could try is simply removing data from local storage in some brief intervals, [chrome.browsingData.removeLocalStorage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browsingData) API method looks like best approach.

If you use [chrome.browsingData.remove](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browsingData) and specify other types of content data it will allow you to remove all forms of data (e.g. cache, websql, indexed DB etc).

Comment: That seems like a big oversight (we block cookies, and sites just use localStorage to do the same thing)... In any case, I need to clear localStorage ONLY for some sites -- I'm not sure that is possible with the method you suggest ?