# Site stored sensitive data locally

Tags: javascript, php

The site stores personal information on the local machine.  This sensitive data contains personal details like their names, their date of birth, their identity card, etc.  This data can be access later by a third party either at the machine through the browser when the user visits their site. How to prevent this case?

```
Screenshots
Attached
```

[image]

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but how does that situation in your image even come to exist?

Comment: In the screenshot,  I had stored information insecurely so i want that information to be secure in the local (js).

Comment: Could we look at your code ?

Comment: In js, i stored this:

`var personalInfoJson = "{personalInfoDataJson}";
  localStorage.setItem("personalInfoDataJson", personalInfoJson);`

Comment: That is browser `localStorage`. Do not set the data if you do not want the domain to read `localStorage`. You can also block setting of `localStorage`.

Comment: See [How can I browse with localstorage disabled?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600754/how-can-i-browse-with-localstorage-disabled)

Comment: *The site stores personal information on the local machine.* By not storing personal information on the local machine.

Answer (score 1):

If you own the site, you can easily clear localStorage as a whole or in pieces. Run this code after you're through using the local data.

`localStorage.clear();`

You can remove specific variables like:

`localStorage.removeItem(key_name);`